# Filter an OData query based on a link count?

Tags: odata

Given a structure where two types are exposed in an OData system with a master/detail relationship:

Order
 - OrderDetails

How would you filter a query of orders based upon the count of associated OrderDetails?  In my head, it's something along the lines of

`/Orders$filter=count(OrderDetails) eq 0`

But, of course there's no count function.  So, how would you produce a list of orders which had no OrderDetails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar question to this one: [Collection Exists Criteria in WCF Data Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390761/collection-exists-criteria-in-wcf-data-services)
Currently the OData protocol doesn't support any operator/query to do that. The best solution is to expose a service operation which exposes this kind of operation from the server directly.

Comment: You're right, that's pretty darn similar.  My search prowess is obviously dulling.